# to_number in postgres returning wrong value

Tags: postgresql

When try to convert the string to number, the postgres to_number returning wrong value.

```
select to_number(amount,'999g999g999D999')/1000000,amount from amount_table;
        ?column?        | amount
------------------------+----------------
 0.08021700000000000000 | 802117
```

the amount should be 0.802170.. not sure what is the issue.. Please any one help here

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column to begin with?

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7d439deb90081077069f28da60fd14ad)

Comment: G and D are locale dependent. if i am not mistaken, some locales don't have group separators. '9999999999D999' should work fine for you even if you have thousand separators in string.